# If $G/H$ and $G$ are connected linear algebraic groups must $H$ also be connected?

Tags: general-topology, number-theory, algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a perfect field (e.g of characteristic zero) and let $G$ and $H$ be linear algebraic groups over $k$, with $H$ a normal subgroup of $G$.

> If both $G$ and $G/H$ are connected, must $H$ also be?

Comment: Since $G/H$ is connected for any connected linear algebraic $k$-group $G$ and closed $k$-subgroup (being a continuous image of $G$), your question is equivalent to: is every closed normal $k$-subgroup of a connected linear algebraic $k$-group connected? This is not true. Finite subgroups exist, and in characteristic zero, these are never connected (if non-trivial)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, if $G$ is connected, then $G/H$ is connected (the map $G\to G/H$ defining the ``quotient" is faithfully flat, in particular surjective). Take a connected linear algebraic group with disconnected center, e.g., $\mathrm{SL}_2$ in characteristic zero. The quotient by the center is connected, but the center isn't connected (it's étale and non-trivial). In general connected semisimple groups have finite center, and in characteristic zero, the center will be étale, hence not connected if non-trivial.